# RavenDB session.Advanced.IsLoaded with transformer

Tags: session, load, ravendb, transformer-model

I am using the Server and Client Build #30155.

Assuming that docId is a string, I am a bit confused about the following API (https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/client-api/session/loading-entities#load):

```
TResult Load<TResult>(
string id,
string transformer,
Action<ILoadConfiguration> configure);
```

When I have loaded (via call to the `session.Load<object>(docId)`) document in a session, and executed the above call, RavenDB returns null for this in-session-only-loaded document, although the document is in a session - `session.IsLoaded(docId)` returns true.

Is the call to:
`session.Load<object>(docId, transformer: transformerName, configure: null)`
aimed to "forcibly" go to the server, cause transformer is provided to run server side, or is it a bug?

However, session.Load(docId) first checks if the document with docId is already contained/loaded in a session, and first then if not, goes to the server and loads it into the session.

Answer (score 0):

A transformer will always go to the server, because we have to run the transformer to know what the result would be.
In contrast, just issuing a load means that we can check the session cache and serve directly from there.